# how to check what exacly request i send to restful webservice via restful client (javax.ws.rs.client)

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I`m looking answer to question how it is possible to check what exacly request body and headers i send to restful webservice using restful client. For example and following code bellow:

```
    // client object
    Client client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();   

    // Web target
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI)

   // Sending a request
      webTarget
       .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
       .cookie(cookie)
       .post(Entity.entity(params,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

how to debug, monitor or overview this request? It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to use something like Postman extension for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

This will allow you to set all relevant headers and the request body and easily debug API calls.